# Simplest way to calculate amount of even numbers in given range

Tags: c, math

What is the simplest way to calculate the amount of even numbers in a range of unsigned integers?

An example: if range is [0...4] then the answer is 3 (0,2,4)

I'm having hard time to think of any simple way. The only solution I came up involved couple of if-statements. Is there a simple line of code that can do this without if-statements or ternary operators?

Comment: Size of the range divided by two?

Comment: @Neil, wouldn't that only apply if the range is always `0..x`?

Comment: @Neil: No that is not always correct.

Comment: @Brian  I know, but as at the time I made my comment everyone was suggesting writing loops, I thought I'd suggest  a simpler approach.

Comment: +1 Because this is more challenging than one might think at first.

Comment: Do you count zero as an even number?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
int even = (0 == begin % 2) ? (end - begin) / 2 + 1 : (end - begin + 1) / 2;
```

Which can be converted into:

```
int even = (end - begin + (begin % 2)) / 2 + (1 - (begin % 2));
```

**EDIT:** This can further simplified into:

```
int even = (end - begin + 2 - (begin % 2)) / 2;
```

**EDIT2:** Because of the in my opinion somewhat incorrect definition of integer division in C (integer division truncates downwards for positive numbers and upwards for negative numbers) this formula won't work when begin is a negative odd number.

**EDIT3:** User 'iPhone beginner' correctly observes that if `begin % 2` is replaced with `begin & 1` this will work correctly for all ranges.

Comment: Doesn't work for the OP's example, i.e. 0..4 should return 3.

Comment: Seems to be wrong. For given example [0..4] `even = (4 - 0 - (0%2)) /2 = 4/2 = 2`. I think `int even = (end - begin - (begin % 2)) / 2 + 1;` is a proper answer

Comment: This only seems to work for ranges starting at 0? Try 10 .. 1

Comment: @Greg K with `end = 10` and `begin = 1` this gives 5 which I think is the correct answer.

Comment: `(10 - 1 - (1%2))/2 + 1 = (8)/2+1 = 5` : 2,4,6,8,10

@Andreas, what do you mean by empty range? There is no such thing as empty inclusive range. This method works for `[a,a]` as well for both odd and even `a`. What's the issue?

Comment: @Andreas You are correct, I had (end - begin + (begin % 2)) / 2 + 1, doh! +1

Comment: @iPhone beginner Ok, empty range isn't the correct term. A range with a single odd element in doesn't work like `[1, 1]` this will incorrectly report 1.

Comment: Surely he can afford a check for that? if (max == min) { ... } else { your answer }

Comment: @Andreas What about new idea:
`int even = (end - begin) / 2 + (!(begin%2)|!(end%2));`
It seems that we need to add +1 to range if either of ranges is even. Edit: Actually it seems to be what Andrei Ciobanu propose

Comment: Yes, it is almost the same as previous one, but 0 is irregular value. (x+2)/2-x/2 = 1 unless x=-1 and (x+2)=1

Comment: @Brian [3..4] Converts into `(4 - 3 + 2 - (3 % 2)) / 2 == 1` which is the correct answer.

Comment: @Vlad You can't create a closed formula when the interval straddles zero because of the (incorrect) discontinuous behavior of integer division in c.

Comment: @Andreas: You can, look at my answer :-)

Comment: `begin-begin%2` can be simplified (or, obfuscated) to `begin/2*2` or `begin&~1`.

Comment: @Vlad But not with C integer division.

Comment: @Andreas: yes. Is that somehow bad?

Comment: @Vlad I don't put any moral aspects on it, but I dont like converting a problem that should be solvable in the integer domain to finite precision floating point numbers. If the actual range do straddle zero, I would add an if-statement (or ternary operator).

Comment: @Andreas: you can code `floor(a/2.0)` as `( a - (a%2)*(a%2) ) / 2`, if you wish to stay at integers. Or any other hack. This would however not add any readability. [Note that the original post asks explicitly for no ternary operators.]

Comment: Nice and simple solution. Now that I see it it seems so simple. This was a good learning experience at least for me. Thanks.

Comment: @Fdr No problem, I think this was an interesting problem as well!

Comment: @Andreas could you give an example of "this formula won't work when the interval straddles 0."? AFAICS it works fine in any case if `end >= begin`, but you can't move `+2` out from `/2` as `+1` because this will break the formula for odd [a,a] ranges. This is the only case I can see when `-(begin % 2)` will make value in `/2` negative and "strange" division rules will apply. Did I miss something?

Comment: `(length >> 1) + (1 & ~start & length)` or `((end - start + 1) >> 1) + (1 & ~start & ~end)` is easier IMO, see my answer.

Comment: @Christoffer Easier in what way?

Comment: @iPhone beginner I was slightly incorrect, I should have written when `begin` is odd and negative. Try it with `[-1, 1]` it should evaluate to 2 on your favorite C compiler.

Comment: @Andreas I see, I totally forgot about this behavior (`-1 % 2 = -1`). So this is the reason to replace `%2` with `&1` that should works as usual people expect `%2` to work for both positive and negative values.

Answer (score 7):

Hint 1: The modulo operator will return the remainder of the current number
Hint 2: You don't need a for loop
Hint 3: A range is continuous
Hint 4: The number of even numbers in a continuous range are half even (sometimes half + 1, sometimes half - 1)
Hint 5: Building on Hint1: Consider also what (being + end + 1) % 2 gives
Hint 6: Most or all of the answers in this thread are wrong
Hint 7: Make sure you try your solution with negative number ranges
Hint 8: Make sure you try your solution with ranges spanning both negative and positive numbers

Comment: that I know, but putting it in a clear sentence is bit difficult. Depending on range there can be n/2 or n/2 + 1 even numbers.

Comment: @Fdr: And consider what would happen if you used it on an endpoint.

Comment: @Vlad: Yes he can put some extra thinking for negative solutions.  I added a hint 7 about that thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Brian In a range beginning with odd and ending with odd, your Hint 4 is incorrect.

Comment: @Kirk: Thanks fixed, I put sometimes -1 as well.

Comment: @Brian Thanks for the hints, although most of them I was aware of. Hints 7&8 were off the mark as I stated that I only needed this for positive integers.

Answer (score 3):

Answer is to use binary AND.

so a number is represented in memory in 0 and 1.
lets say 4 and 5.

4 = 0000 0100

5 = 0000 0101

and every even number has a zero in the end and every odd number has 1 in the end;

in c '1' means true and '0' means false.

so: lets code;

```
function isEven(int num){
     return ((num & 0x01) == 0) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Here 0x01 means 0000 0001.
so we are anding 0x01 with the given number.

imagine no is 5

```
5    |0000 0101 

0x01 |0000 0001

---------------

      0000 0001
```

so answer will be '1'.

imagine no is 4

```
4    |0000 0100 

0x01 |0000 0001

---------------

      0000 0000
```

so answer will be '0'.

now,

```
return ((num & 0x01) == 0) ? 1 : 0;
```

it is expanded in :

```
if((num & 0x01) == 0){// means  the number is even
      return 1;
}else{//means no is odd
      return 0;
}
```

So this is all.

End is binary operatiors are very important in compititive programming world.

happy coding.

first answer here.

EDIT 1:

Total no of evens are

```
totalEvens = ((end - start) / 2 + ((((end - start) & 0x01 ) == 0) ? 0 : 1 ));
```

here
`(end - start)/2` gives the half of total numbers.

this works if one is even and one is odd.

but,

```
((((end - start) & 0x01 ) == 0) ? 0 : 1 )
```

can just replaced by `(!isEven(end-start))`

So, if the total number is even then dont add 1 else add 1.

this completely works.

Answer (score 2):

```
int start, stop;
start = 0;
stop = 9;
printf("%d",(stop-start)/2+((!(start%2) || !(stop%2)) ? 1 : 0));
```

Where *start* and *stop* can hold any value. 
No need to iterate to to determine this number.

Answer (score 2):

The count of even numbers between 0 and *n* is [*n*/2] + 1. Therefore the count of even numbers between (*n* + 1) and *m* is ([*m*/2] + 1) - ([*n*/2] + 1) = [*m*/2] - [*n*/2].

For count of even numbers between *m* and *n* the answer therefore would be [*m*/2] - [(*n* - 1)/2].

The [x] is taken to the direction of -\infty. Beware that the usual C integer division is not doing right in our case: `a/2` is rounded towards zero, not -\infty, so the result will be not [*a*/2] for teh case of negative *a*.

This should be the simplest calculation; works for negative numbers, too. (Needs however that *m* >= *n*.) Doesn't contain `if`s and `?:`s.

If you don't consider negative numbers, you can use just `m/2 - (n+1)/2 + 1`, otherwise `floor(m/2.0) - floor((n-1)/2.0)`

Answer (score 2):

This'll do the trick, even for ranges with negative numbers.

```
int even = (last - first + 2 - Math.abs(first % 2) - Math.abs(last % 2)) / 2;
```

Tested with the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] numbers = {{0, 4}, {0, 5}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {4, 4}, {5, 5},
                       {-1, 0}, {-5, 0}, {-4, 5}, {-5, 5}, {-4, -4}, {-5, -5}};

    for (int[] pair : numbers) {
        int first = pair[0];
        int last = pair[1];
        int even = (last - first + 2 - Math.abs(first % 2) - Math.abs(last % 2)) / 2;
        System.out.println("[" + first + ", " + last + "] -> " + even);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[0, 4] -> 3
[0, 5] -> 3
[1, 4] -> 2
[1, 5] -> 2
[4, 4] -> 1
[5, 5] -> 0
[-1, 0] -> 1
[-5, 0] -> 3
[-4, 5] -> 5
[-5, 5] -> 5
[-4, -4] -> 1
[-5, -5] -> 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The range is always [2a+b, 2c+d] with b,d = {0,1}. Make a table:

```
b d | #even
0 0 | c-a+1
0 1 | c-a+1
1 0 | c-a
1 1 | c-a+1
```

Now a = min/2, b = min % 2, c = max/2 and d = max % 2.

So `int nEven = max/2 - min/2 + 1 - (min%2)`.

Comment: Nice answer. Clear, real physicist answer. Welcome in the 10k club! :-)

Comment: @peterh Thank you twice :-) 10k via one of my oldest posts 

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit surprised that iteration was tried to solve this.
The minimum number of even numbers possible in a range is equal to half of the length of the array of numbers, or, rangeEnd - rangeStart.
Add 1 if the first or last number is even.

So the method is: (using javascript)

```
function evenInRange(rangeStart, rangeEnd)
{
  return
    Math.floor(rangeEnd - rangeStart) + 
    ((rangeStart % 2 == 0) || (rangeEnd % 2 == 0) ? 1 : 0)
}


Tests:
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
8 - 0 = 8
8 / 2 = 4
4 + 1 = 5
Even numbers in range:
0 2 4 6 8

11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
20 - 11 = 9
9 / 2 = 4
4 + 1 = 5
Even numbers in range
12 14 16 18 20

1 2 3
3 - 1 = 2
2 / 2 = 1
1 + 0 = 1
Even numbers in range
2

2 3 4 5
5 - 2 = 3
3 / 2 = 1
1 + 1 = 2
Even numbers in range
2 4

2 3 4 5 6
6 - 2 = 4
4 / 2 = 2
2 + 1 = 3
Even numbers in range
2 4 6
```

Comment: Your tests all divide by 2 but your formula doesn't include a division at all.

Comment: You're correct, it should say 
Math.floor((rangeEnd - rangeStart) / 2)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd say

```
(max - min + 1 + (min % 2)) / 2
```

Edit: Erm okay for some reason I thought that (min % 2) returns 1 for even numbers.... :). The correct version is

```
(max - min + 1 + 1 - (min % 2)) / 2
```

or rather

```
(max - min + 2 - (min % 2)) / 2
```

Comment: What if `min` and `max` are both 1?

Comment: The requirements talk about unsigned integers ;). (Btw none of the methods here work for negative numbers because of the way division and modulo are handled for negative numbers in C.)

Answer (score 0):

The first even number in the range is: `(begin + 1) & ~1` (round `begin` up to even number).

The last even number in the range is: `end & ~1` (round `end` down to even number).

The total number of even numbers in the range is therefore: `(end & ~1) - ((begin + 1) & ~1) + 1`.

```
int num_evens = (end & ~1) - ((begin + 1) & ~1) + 1;
```

Comment: Is the ~1 function defined?  Nice clean algorithm but I do not know of such a function.

Comment: @Kirk: `~` is the bitwise unary NOT operator in C/C++. So `~1` is an int with all but the LS bit set to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at this logically ...

We have four cases ...

```
odd -> odd     eg.  1 -> 3  answer: 1
odd -> even    eg.  1 -> 4  answer: 2
even -> odd    eg.  0 -> 3  answer: 2
even -> even   eg.  0 -> 4  answer: 3
```

The first three cases can be handled simply as ...

```
(1 + last - first) / 2
```

The fourth case does not fall quite so nicely into this, but we can fudge around a little bit for it quite easily ...

```
answer = (1 + last - first) / 2;
if (both first and last are even)
    answer++;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Oh well, why not:

```
#include <cassert>

int ecount( int begin, int end ) {
    assert( begin <= end );
    int size = (end - begin) + 1;
    if ( size % 2 == 0  || begin % 2 == 1 ) {
        return size / 2;
    }
    else {
        return size / 2 + 1;
    }
}

int main() {
    assert( ecount( 1, 5 ) == 2 );
    assert( ecount( 1, 6 ) == 3 );
    assert( ecount( 2, 6 ) == 3 );
    assert( ecount( 1, 1 ) == 0 );
    assert( ecount( 2, 2 ) == 1 );
}
```

Comment: It makes sense but it's not a single line of code with `if` statements.

Comment: It's the "easiest" solution, IMHO - which was the headline question. I can't see any possible reason for writing it as  a one-liner.

Comment: @Neil - there are plenty here!  Surely one must be correct! ;)  try mine, for example.

Comment: @Neil: My reason is curiosity. Not knowing a solution, doesn't mean that there isn't one.

Comment: @Neil Without the one-line, no `if` requirement the problem is too easy.

Comment: @Kirk artificially difficult problems are  a waste of time, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

The answer:

```
(max - min + 2 - (max % 2) - (min % 2)) / 2
```

A short explanation:

- even..even yields (length + 1) / 2
- even..odd yields length / 2
- odd..even yields length / 2
- odd..odd yields (length - 1) / 2
- length = max - min + 1

Therefore, the answer is `(length - 1) / 2` plus `1/2` for even min plus `1/2` for even max.
Note that `(length - 1) / 2 == (max - min) / 2`, and the "bonuses" are `(1 - (min % 2)) / 2` and `(1 - (max % 2)) / 2`.  Sum this all up and simplify to obtain the answer above.

Comment: Right.  It should be: (max - min + 2 - (abs(max) % 2) - (abs(min) % 2)) / 2.

Comment: On the other hand, the question explicitly states "a range of unsigned integers".

Answer (score 0):

In terms of start and length:

`(length >> 1) + (1 & ~start & length)`

half the length plus 1 if start is even and length is odd.

In terms of start and end:

`((end - start + 1) >> 1) + (1 & ~start & ~end)`

half the length plus 1 if start is even and end is even.

Comment: I'm a bit proud of using bitwise AND as a conditional actually. :)

Answer (score 0):

This does not require any conditions at all:

```
evencount = floor((max - min)/2) + 1
```

Answer (score -3):

Pseudo code (i'm no C coder):

```
count = 0;
foreach(i in range){
    if(i % 2 == 0){
      count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: O(n) is way too expensive (...and ugly)